# An exponential map from CL(4,R) to Spin(3,1) which is surjective?

Tags: group-theory, clifford-algebras, spin-geometry

I am trying to find an algebra whose exponential maps surjectively to Spin(3,1).

I understand that its lie algebra is $\mathfrak{so}(3,1)$, but I think it leaves elements out.

I am working with the bivectors of CL(4,R).

$$
\mathbf{f} = E_{01}\gamma_0\gamma_1+E_{02}\gamma_0\gamma_2 + E_{03}\gamma_0\gamma_3+B_{12}\gamma_1\gamma_2+B_{13}\gamma_1\gamma_3+B_{23}\gamma_2\gamma_3
$$

Its exponential is

$$
e^{\mathbf{f}}=\cos \theta+  \left( \sin \theta \right) \left(  E_{01}\gamma_0\gamma_1+E_{02}\gamma_0\gamma_2 + E_{03}\gamma_0\gamma_3+B_{12}\gamma_1\gamma_2+B_{13}\gamma_1\gamma_3+B_{23}\gamma_2\gamma_3 \right)
$$

where $\theta = ||   E_{01}\gamma_0\gamma_1+E_{02}\gamma_0\gamma_2 + E_{03}\gamma_0\gamma_3+B_{12}\gamma_1\gamma_2+B_{13}\gamma_1\gamma_3+B_{23}\gamma_2\gamma_3||$

---

However, the official definition of spin relates to multiplying an even number of vectors together whose norm is +1 (or -1).

Such multiplication can produce linear combinasions of scalars, pseudo-scalars and bivectors.

Yet, the exponential of a bivector can only produce scalars and bivectors. Thus, it must be incomplete.

---

I note that if I add a pseudo-scalar  $\mathbf{z}$ to my bivector $\mathbf{f}$, I get

$$
\mathbf{f} + \mathbf{z} = E_{01}\gamma_0\gamma_1+E_{02}\gamma_0\gamma_2 + E_{03}\gamma_0\gamma_3+B_{12}\gamma_1\gamma_2+B_{13}\gamma_1\gamma_3+B_{23}\gamma_2\gamma_3 + Z\gamma_0\gamma_1\gamma_2\gamma_3
$$

Its exponential is:

$$
e^{\mathbf{f} + \mathbf{z}}=\cos \theta+  \left( \sin \theta \right) \left(  E_{01}\gamma_0\gamma_1+E_{02}\gamma_0\gamma_2 + E_{03}\gamma_0\gamma_3+B_{12}\gamma_1\gamma_2+B_{13}\gamma_1\gamma_3+B_{23}\gamma_2\gamma_3 + Z \gamma_0\gamma_1\gamma_2\gamma_3\right)
$$

---

From this, it appears that the exponential map of $\mathbf{f}+\mathbf{z}$ is surjective to ${\rm Spin}(3,1)$.

Is this correct?

Is it bijective?

Finally, is $\mathbf{f}+\mathbf{z}$=$\mathfrak{so}(3,1) \oplus \mathfrak{u}(1)$?

Comment: your formula for $e^{\mathbf{f}}$ is not correct, $e^{\mathbf{f}}$ contains also 4-vectors in general

Comment: @user8268 Can you give me a simple example?

Comment: @user8268 Or if you know what the correct formula for $e^\mathbf{f}$, then even better.

Comment: no full formula, but say $\exp(\gamma_0\gamma_1 + \gamma_2\gamma_3)$ (computed as a power series) contains $(\gamma_0\gamma_1 + \gamma_2\gamma_3)^2/2$, which contains $\gamma_0\gamma_1\gamma_2\gamma_3$

Comment: @user8268 Thank you.